# Search all words in the input field, then replace all matching words in the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#srctxt div').each(function() {
    var dari = $('#box').val();
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(text.replace(dari, '<b>'+dari+'</b>')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">

<input type="text" id="box" value="love"> // working
<input type="text" id="box" value="love girl"> // not working

<div id="srctxt">
<div>i love you</div>
<div>love girl</div>
<div>not love</div>
<div>love love love</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm developing a search site by bolding every matching word of the input word with search results.

If only a word is entered, such as the word `love`, then this script works quite well. But if using two or more words, then this script does not work properly.

for example the word `love girl`, then the bold on the results for only one line. but it all contains the word love, so this is a problem for me.

sorry if my English is a bit hard to understand. however, I am asking for suggestions of this jQuery code fix. Thank you...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Works for me also with the two words. Please provide a demo so we can see it does not work for you.

Comment: I hope you don't mean that you have both `input` elements with `id="box"` there at the *same* time, because then it is logical the second one does not do anything. HTML requires that all `id` attributes are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can easily do this using regex**

Here are the steps:

**Step-1.** Split the `input value` to make an `array of input words`.

**Step-2.** Iterate over all the `div` for which you want to execute search/replace condition

**Step-3.** For each `word in input array` create a `searchregexp` and replace if found

```js
if ($('#box').val().length !== 0) {
   var dari = $('#box').val().split(' ');
   $('#srctxt div').each(function() {
       dari.map(item => {
         var regex = new RegExp('(' + item + ')(?!>|b>)', 'gi');
         $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>"));
          });       
      });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="box" value="love girl b"> 

<div id="srctxt">
<div>i love you</div>
<div>love girl</div>
<div>not love</div>
<div>love love love</div>
</div>
```

Also I removed the duplicate input field having same id as it is invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to loop through your text in the search field. Assuming no special characters (-,{,}, > etc) are entered you can do following

```
$('#srctxt div').each(function() {
    var dari = $('#box').val().split(" ");
    var text = $(this).text();
    dar.map((val, index) => {
        $(this).html(text.replace(val, '<b>'+val+'</b>')); 
    });
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you, but this only thicken the most recent word

Comment: You mean most recent word in search??? Like for "Love girl", only "girl" is bold??
You will have to provide more context on "this". Do have any id/class on the element that contains all the text that you want to bold the search words in
?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to `split` your search query, like:

`'love girl'.split(' '); // ---> ['love','girl'];`

and do a `forEach` on the resulting array and behave each one like your `dari` variable.
note that even if your word is one word, (like "love"), the result of `split` would still be an array. so you do not need to separate your logic into two branches.